# Connection Timeout when connecting to Bluetooth LE devices

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, bluetooth, dell

I have a problem connecting to Bluetooth LE devices on my Dell XPS 13" 9360. It worked fine before, but suddenly connecting to a device always fails with connection timeout. I've tested with 10+ devices and connect always fails with the same error. The devices works, it is possible to connect to them from another computer.

I'm using `BlueZ 5.50 (bluetoothctl)` and Ubuntu 16.04 (just upgraded to 18.04 but still same problem).

Output from bluetoothctl:

```
[bluetooth]# connect D6:37:A6:25:93:E6
Attempting to connect to D6:37:A6:25:93:E6
[CHG] Device D6:37:A6:25:93:E6 Connected: yes
Connection successful
[CHG] Device D6:37:A6:25:93:E6 Connected: no
```

Disconnect "Connected: no" happens about 1 second after Connection successful.

Output from `hcidump -i hci0` while connecting:

```
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    LE Create Connection (0x08|0x000d) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Disconn Complete (0x05) plen 4
    status 0x00 handle 5 reason 0x08
    Reason: Connection Timeout
```

Output from `hciconfig -a`:

```
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
BD Address: 9C:B6:D0:D5:AF:B6  ACL MTU: 1024:8  SCO MTU: 50:8
UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
RX bytes:14656 acl:16 sco:0 events:1504 errors:0
TX bytes:17087 acl:17 sco:0 commands:1001 errors:0
Features: 0xff 0xfe 0x8f 0xfe 0xd8 0x3f 0x5b 0x87
Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF 
Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
Name: 'foo'
Class: 0x1c010c
Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer
Device Class: Computer, Laptop
HCI Version: 4.1 (0x7)  Revision: 0x0
LMP Version: 4.1 (0x7)  Subversion: 0x25a
Manufacturer: Qualcomm (29)
```

What i've tested so far:

- Rebooted computer
- Power off / power on in bluetoothctl
- Connected both with scan on and scan off
- Removed device -> scan / discover it again
- Cleared cache (`sudo rm -rf
  /var/lib/bluetooth/[controllerid]` followed by `sudo service restart
  bluetooth`)
- Changed supervision timeout from 42 to 2000 (`/sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/supervision_timeout`)
- Modified link mode from `SLAVE ACCEPT` to `MASTER`
- Tried connecting with `hcitool lecc`, but same error
- Upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04
- Upgraded my BIOS to latest version

No bluetooth config files are modified in `/etc/bluetooth/`

The problem started with just one or two devices, then all of a sudden it was not possible to connect to any devices anymore.

Is there another cache to clear? Any value / timeout length or operating mode that could have been changed?

Comment: Remove bluez and install blueman from the repos - it's a real bluetooth manager compared to bluez

Comment: But after all that updating/upgrading/editing/cache clearing and whatever else you did, it's anyone's guess if it works properly now

Comment: Thanks for your comments @beertempest I just went out for lunch and when i got back I couldnt connect to any Bluetooth LE devices anymore. It was after that i did the clearing/editing and even upgrading to get it to work again.
blueman seems to be just a GUI using bluez and D-bus as backend.